# "Sex" sci-fi TV show from the 90s about a girl in her spaceship

Tags: identify-this-movie, identify-this-tv-show, science-fiction

I would like some help identifying a TV show (or possibly a movie) that I saw when I was between five and ten (that makes it between 15 and 20 year ago).

From what I remember the plot was about a girl in her spaceship and a secondary male character that was maybe the spaceship itself or a robot (I just remember the voice).

During that episode they landed on a planet and the girl was attacked by small puppet-like robots with sharp teeth (which really scared the shit out of me at the time, that's why I want to find this back so I can see). She was eventually saved and I remember whipping sounds so that could have involved a whip.

I also remember that sex may have been part of the plot (one of the opening line was something about sex discoveries/stuff, and the girl was in suggestive outfit) but it was not too hardcore because it didn't seem to bother the other adults watching this with me that a child could watch it.

I was watching this in French on French TV between 1996 and 2001, but given the production it should have been something that was translated.

From my researches it could have been from the series *Lexx* (it fits the sex and sci-fi theme) but I can't locate the episode if it really is from *Lexx*.

Comment: Multiple episodes of the lexx featured robot drones that are destroying the light universe throughout season 2 and parts of 4.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sounds likethe movie [Barbarella](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barbarella_(film)) (1968)

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barbarella_(film)):

> Barbarella is a 1968 French-Italian science fiction film based on Jean-Claude Forest's French Barbarella comics. [...]
>
> Barbarella crashes on the 16th planet of Tau Ceti [...] They set out several dolls which have razor-sharp teeth. As the dolls begin to bite her, Barbarella faints but is rescued by Mark Hand, [...] . While Hand takes her back to her ship, Barbarella offers to reward Mark and he suggests sex [...]

You can check the trailer of the film at [youtube](https://youtu.be/0Xo6FaypcpY)

Comment: The stars must have just aligned because I found it 5min ago, just had the time to watch the dolls scene (god they are creepy!). Thank you very much anyway (I was far from it with the year and the fact that it is a movie).